# Сложный запрос в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, table

Уже третий день сижу пытаюсь сочинить запрос на SQL. Есть у меня вот такая схема данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать запрос, который собирает данные об установленном ПО к каждом кабинете.
Пока есть только один стабильно работающий запрос по этой теме:

```
SELECT software.*, licenses.name as 'l_name', licenses.doc_num 
FROM software
LEFT JOIN licenses
ON software.license_id = licenses.id
```

Как сделать такой же запрос, только еще с привязкой к кабинету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно:

```
SELECT c.name, s.*, l.name as 'l_name', l.doc_num 
FROM software s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.license_id = l.id
JOIN workplace_software ws ON ws.software_id = s.id
JOIN workplaces w ON w.id = ws.workplace_id
JOIN cabinet_workplaces cw ON cw.workplace_id = w.id
JOIN cabinets c ON c.id = cw.cabinet_id
ORDER BY c.name
```

Почему-то лицензии догадались включить в запрос, а остальное по аналогии не догадались. Даже не смотря на схему с линиями связи.

Answer (score 0):

В данной схеме не получиться узнать, то что вы хотите. У Вас нет связи между cabinets и software.
Вы можете сделать cross join, но это умножение всех на все.

Вам нужно добавить таблицу

```
CabinetSoftware (id, cabinet_id, sowtware_id)
```

и будет всё хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы связать cabinets и software нужно поле. Добавьте в таблицу software поле cabinet_id. Если у каждого софта есть своя лицензия, то можно удалить licenses перенеся все поля оттуда в software.

Comment: Не получится так, там идет связь многие-ко-многим. В каждом кабинете может быть установлено разное ПО, и разное ПО может быть установлено в разных кабинетах.

Comment: Точнее даже не так, ПО не в кабинетах, ПО на рабочих местах, а уже рабочие места в кабинетах

Comment: А может быть много лицензий на одно ПО?